# Compare two arrays and replace elements without duplicating - c++

Tags: c++, arrays, compare

I can't seem to figure out how to compare two arrays in C++, myArray1 & myArray2, and replace the zeros in myArray1 with elements from myArray2 without duplicating any numbers. Essentially, I want to replace the two zeros with 1 & 3 - in any order....

```
int myArray1[4] = [0,2,0,4]
int myArray2[4] = [1,2,3,4]
```

I'd like the output to be:

```
myArray1[4] = [1,2,3,4] -or- [3,2,1,4]
```

Any help would be great, and sorry if this is a repeat question.

Comment: Will `myArray2` have any zeros in it?

Comment: What do you mean by *without duplicating and numbers*?  `myArray1` can't have duplicates or you cannot use the same number to fill it from `myArray2`?

Comment: Looks like a homework to me...

Comment: This appears straightforward. Simply copy corresponding elements if the target element is zero. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: These two arrays are just short examples so I can figure out the coding side of it. Each array can be in any order and myArray2 will never have a zero in it....

Comment: Just for clarification, if `myArray2` was e.g. `{ 2, 1, 4, 3 }` the end result would *still* be `{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }` or `{ 3, 2, 1, 4 }`? And *not* simply copying the `2` and `4` from `myArray2` giving e.g. the result `{ 2, 2, 4, 4 }`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, my inner telepath tells me you're right.

Comment: Correct, myArray1 and myArray2 need to have all the same numbers without repeating any and regardless of what order they are in.

Answer (score 0):

The naive solution would be to loop over `myArray1` to find the zeroes, and when one is found loop over `myArray2` to find the first element not existing in `myArray1` (which will be done in another nested loop).

So you will have three loops, each one nested in the other.

In pseudo-code

```
for each value1 in myArray1:
    if value1 = 0:
        for each value2 in myArray2:
            // Check that the value from myArray2 doesn't exist in myArray1
            found = false

            for each tempValue1 in myArray1:
                if value2 = tempValue1:
                    found = true  // Found a duplicate
                    break out of loop

            if not found:
                value1 = value2
                break out of loop
```

Answer (score 0):

according to what i understood, this might be the solution:

```
int main(){

int myArray1[4] = {0,2,0,4};
int myArray2[4] = {1,2,3,4};

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++)
{
    for (int j = i; j <4 ; j++) {

        if (myArray1[i] == 0) {
            myArray1[i] = myArray2[j];

        }
    }
}
for(int i = 0;i<4;++i){
    cout<<myArray1[i]<<" ";
}


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your task can be solved with set operations:

```
const size_t N = 4;
int a[N] = {0,2,0,4};
int b[N] = {1,2,3,4};
int r[N] = {};
{
    std::sort(a, a+N);
    std::sort(b, b+N);
    // invariant: the a set must be in the b set
    std::set_union(a, std::remove(a, a+N, 0), b, b+N, r);
}
for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    std::cout << i << ":" << r[i] << std::endl;
```